# How to specify pem file path when using gateway in Fabric

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, fabric

I have followed many question related to this topic.

My scenario:

> Local host -> Gateway -> Remote host

I am using env.gateway variable to specify gateway host.

sample code

```
env.user = "ec2-user"

env.key_filename = ["/home/ec2-user/.ssh/internal.pem","/home/roshan.r/test.pem","/home/ec2-user/.ssh/test2.pem"]

env.hosts = ['x.x.x.244', 'x.x.x.132']      
env.gateway = 'x.x.x.189'

def getdate():
    content = run('date')
```

My problem is with pem key path.

/home/roshan.r/test.pem is located in current directory. which is used for login into gateway server.

Other two mentioned pem files are located in gateway server.

When i run this program i'm getting file not found error.

Thanks for any help !!

Answer (score 0):

I havn't had to do this yet, but what about having a function that fecth those pem file ? something like :

```
@'x.x.x.189'
def get_pem():
    env.key_filename.append(get("/home/ec2-user/.ssh/internal.pem")
    env.key_filename.append(get("/home/ec2-user/.ssh/test2.pem")
```

Also, I could you try something ? i guess you got a fiel not found because fabric is looking for the `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/internal.pem` on your computer. It has no way knowing it's on a remote host. What if you try with : 
`x.x.x.189:/home/ec2-user/.ssh/internal.pem`

Answer (score 0):

I just changed path of the .pem file and It works. See below suggestion:

Keep gateway and app server .pem file in your local machine and try to execute it. See below my code.

```
from fabric.api import *

env.user = "ubuntu"

env.key_filename = ["~/folder/sub_folder/gate_way_instance.pem", "~/folder/sub_folder/test_server_ssh-key.pem"]

env.hosts = ['XX.XX.XX.XXX']
env.gateway = 'XX.XX.XX.XXX'


def uptime():
    content = run('cat /proc/uptime')
    print content
    content = run('ls -la')
    print content
```